# Ruby on rails application not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailer

I am new here, very experienced in Linux, very new at Ruby.

I have fully reinstalled an old damaged Debian 7.8 server running a Ruby On Rails application with PostgreSql db.

To run the new installation, I had to change the *Gemfile* to adapt to new ruby packages versions.

The new server is running Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) and all ruby packages have been installed from debian packages for system-wide use.

Now it's running ruby 2.3.3, pretty well. First time I have installed such server, I am pretty proud of this.

But emails can't be sent from the application. I can send an email from this server using the Linux mail command, sendmail daemon is running, but the ruby app can't send emails.

I got the errors initially, then i changed the mail paramters in the *config/environments/production.rb* as follows, and no more errors apparently:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "mailserver.com",
    port: 465,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
    :host => Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    :protocol => 'https' 
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {
    from: "Centre Sesame <contact@mailserver.com>",
    reply_to: "contact@mailserver.com"
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I searched in the production logs for some request to send an email:

```
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:08.110776 #17945]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/password/new" for xx.yyy.zzz.15 at 2018-07-02 19:16:08 +0200
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:08.114272 #17945]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as HTML
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:08.123870 #17945]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:08.124890 #17945]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_topbar.html.erb (0.2ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:08.125064 #17945]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:08.125255 #17945]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 9.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.617686 #17945]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/password" for xx.yyy.zzz.15 at 2018-07-02 19:16:11 +0200
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.619438 #17945]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.619535 #17945]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yI1T7u39N/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl8EqvuXupFiijmMtMDHimdtsGMIKkF9HzP17PMsEflWdFn/g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"name@yahoo.fr"}, "commit"=>"Valider"}
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.630951 #17945]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.632109 #17945]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_topbar.html.erb (0.2ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.632296 #17945]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2018-07-02T19:16:11.632480 #17945]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Where should I lookup for more details? Did I miss something?

Apparently everything is correct, no error.

Where should I find errors.

Of course I have checked email account credentials on email server.

Could you help?

Many thanks.

Patrick

Comment: Well, status of `sendmail` is irrelevant, you're not using it. Check if your credentials and connection settings for serverxxxx.com are correct.

Comment: I think you are missing a couple of closing braces (`}`).

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: good eye!

Comment: Sergio, Thanks for this remark, but braces are OK, I just removed (maybe a bad idea) to show only essential parameters.

Comment: I assume you send your emails with `.deliver_later`. Is your background worker running?

Comment: @Patrick yeah, very bad idea. Bring them back.

Comment: the full file with braces:

Comment: background.worker? I even don't know how to check it. Maybe your are right. How to check if it is running? What should start it?

Comment: @Patrick "How to check if it is running?" - well, if you set up the whole server and didn't set up auto-start for the worker, then it's safe to assume it is not running. First you have to find out what is the worker this app uses (DJ, resque, sidekiq or something else), then read its documentation on how to start it properly.

Comment: Sidekiq is running from init.d script # ps -ef|fgrep sidekiq
sesame   18173     1  0 juin18 ?       01:31:50 sidekiq 5.1.3 Sesame [0 of 25 busy]

Comment: "Sidekiq is running" - well, shit. I thought it would be as easy as starting it. This now needs interactive troubleshooting, something which is this site is not designed for.

Comment: Because I tried to copy all settings from the old server, I found this sidekiq and set the init.d script. Maybe I missed somewhere some parameter to have the app sending in some "sidekiq queue", or maybe sidekiq parameters don't have mailer active? What do you think is "interactive troubleshooting"?

Comment: "What do you think is "interactive troubleshooting"?" - something that would shorten the feedback loop for an expert/answerer. Like a remote desktop access or a live shell.

Comment: Can you show the line thats used for sending email? Also, what service are you using to send emails? does it have a log for your account to see if that mail server is getting mail from your app?